# datepicker is not firing beforshow event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Below is my code for a datepicker in dialog box which works good but I want to set my default date and calender date as per the php server time not as per the local timezone.
for that I am trying to do a beforeshow but which is not firing at all.

Any suggestions from anyone???

```
        $('#chooseDt').click(function() { 
                $("#Date_calendar").dialog({
                        open: function(event, ui) {
                                    $( "#dpicker" ).datepicker({
                                        autoSize: true,
                                        showOtherMonths: true,
                                        numberOfMonths: 3,                          
                                        showCurrentAtPos: 1,
                                        onSelect: function(input, inst) {
                                            var currentDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);
                                            var unixdate = currentDate.getTime() / 1000;
                                            $(this).datepicker('destroy');
                                            $(this).parent("div#Date_calendar").dialog( "close" );
                                            window.location.href="xxxxxx.php?homeday="+(unixdate);
                                        },
                                        beforeShow: function() {
                                            alert("A");
                                            //var theDate = new Date();
                                            //theDate.setDate('<?php echo date("d",strtotime($c_date)); ?>');
                                            // calenderDate is my global php variable with date used as currentdate in my php page
                                            //$(this).datepicker('option','defaultDate',calenderDate);         
                                        }
                                    });
                        },
                        close: function(event,ui) {
                            $(this).datepicker('destroy');
                        },
                        resizable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        minWidth: 760
                }).height("auto");
                $( "#Date_calendar" ).dialog('widget').css({'top' : '25%', 'left' : '30%','margin-top' : '-10%', 'margin-left' : '-100px'});    
            return false;   
    });
```

Comment: fiddle for better understanding can any one pleaseee help

http://jsfiddle.net/EL5kR/3/

Comment: Can you explain the problem in fewer words?

Comment: please refer the fiddle i just want to fire beforeshow event

Comment: Seems like `beforeShow` does not fire for inline datepickers.

Comment: You can simply call the `$("#dpicker").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", theDate);` instead of using `beforeShow`.

Comment: badly need the solution i want to set my default date as per the PHP server timezone which comes from database.
so if user changes the timezone all content related changes as per the timezone

Comment: already tried with that code no success

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24103/discussion-between-salman-a-and-nimmi)